# Override chrome binary path when using docker node.js image

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to use chrome instead of my chromium with pupetter. on my local i am over wirting the chrome binary path like this

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: false,
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
  });
```

I want to deploy the application to server using docker and kubernetes. Below are my docker file  contents

```
FROM node:12.16.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install pm2 -g

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "server.js"]
```

Can i use chrome when using node.js image or do i have to use an ubuntu image and then download and configure necessary binary?

Any help on how to fix this would be really great. Thanks.